# Rounding products prices in Magento 1.8 CE

Tags: currency, rounding

I need to round the products prices with precision 2, but with the last decimal equal to 0 or 5.
Example:

```
16,50€
76,70€
5,05€
```

Inserted prices have precision 4.

```
16,5963 need to be -> 16,60
16,5388 need to be -> 16,55
```

How can I do it?

Comment: All the rounded prices must be in exceed:
Ex:
4,53 must be 4,55
4,56 must be 4,60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento way of generating a price with currency symbol:

```
$pow = pow(10, 2); 
$someprice = (ceil($pow * $someprice) + ceil($pow * $someprice - ceil($pow * $someprice))) / $pow;
$someprice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($someprice, true, false);
```

Note that you need to pass false as the third argument if you don't want to returned price to have a containing `<span class="price">` element - both the second and third arguments are true by default.

Non Magento way to just format a float value for 2 decimal places:

```
$pow = pow(10, 2); 
$someprice = (ceil($pow * $someprice) + ceil($pow * $someprice - ceil($pow * $someprice))) / $pow;
$someprice = number_format($someprice, 2);
```

Comment: Where I can set this? In which file?

Comment: You haven't said anything about what you are trying to do so i can't answer that - I've just answered question as you put it.

Comment: I only need to round the products prices.
The admin inserts "T-shirt 5,93€ ect.." and Magento modifies the price in 5,95€.

Comment: See the edit - improved calculation.  If you don't want the currency in the price use the non Magento method.

Comment: Sorry for my inconvenience, but I don't know in which file of the core Magento does the calculation of the subtotal and the big total. For example /app/code/core/.....

Comment: If you have another query you should create another question - what you are asking now is not related to the original question which was just how to perform a calculation.  If you found my calculations to work can you mark the answer as accepted?